# get most common element but if frequencies match, get lower element

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been using `max(Counter(a_list_here),key=Counter(a_list_here).get)` to get the most common element.

However when there are 2 elements which have matching frequencies I want to get the element that is the smallest. For example:

`a= [1,2,5,5,8,8,5,7,8]`

There are three 5s and three 8s. My function `max(Counter(a),key=Counter(a).get)` produces 8 instead of 5.

Is there anyway to do this quickly and cleanly?

I'm using python 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, there's no need to sort it first:

```
from collections import Counter
a = [1,2,5,5,8,8,5,7,8]
```

In Python 2.7:

```
max(Counter(a).iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,-k))[0]
=> 5
```

In Python 3.x:

```
max(Counter(a).items(), key=lambda p: (p[1],-p[0]))[0]
=> 5
```

Comment: This is `O(n)` complexity

Comment: great! However I'm getting a syntax error at the bracket in `(k,v)` ...Is that a python 3 difference?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Really interesting that you can't use key value for python 3. Anyways this works and is the linear solution I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the fastest way, but:

```
sorted([x for x in a if a.count(x) > 1])[0]

>>> a= [1,2,5,5,8,8,5,7,8]
>>> sorted([x for x in a if a.count(x) > 1])[0]
5
```

Comment: n log n - n to go through the list then n log n to sort